# How to bind clicking both left and right mouse button to close window in openbox

Tags: linux, debian, mouse, xorg, openbox

How to bind clicking both left and right mouse button to close current window in openbox? I want to keep the middle button for other action.

Comment: You may easily generalise what is explained here, http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2006/04/mapping-unsupported-keys-with-xmodmap.html

Comment: Looks like xbindkeys can change the binding for a single button, is there any way to bind two buttons?